# How to insert values into SQL field with a key connection

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, ssh, console-application

I've got a table called `Devices`
 `Devices` has a key field called `Names`.
 As well there are fields; `DeviceIP`, `DoesBackup`, `DeviceType`, and `LastBackup`

Field `LastBackup` currently has no knowledge of a devices last backup, the app I am writing will SSH the FTP to find that information.

Now I'm using splits and arrays to break the SSH responses into device name and `lastbackup`, turning them each into a variable.

Now I need to insert `LastBackup` into the empty field in my SQL while maintaining pairing to each device based on it's key `Name`.

I am not sure how to accomplish this as I've read you cannot use a `WHERE` clause with `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

To insert or update a record (insert if not exists, update if exists) you need a query like this.

First you build the connection object and the command object, then set the commandtext to an sql insert operation with the clause that if the record with the primary key exists (the device name) you want an update instead of an insert.
Finally you add the parameters required by the command (the @xxxx strings) and call `ExecuteNonQuery`.

```
using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(..put a connstring here...))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
{
    cnn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO devices 
                      (Names, DeviceIP, DoesBackup, DeviceType, LastBackup)
                      VALUES (@name, @ip, @backs, @type, @last)
                      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE LastBackup=@last";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", variableWithDeviceNameValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", variableWithIPValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@backs", variableWithDoesBackupValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", variableWithDeviceTypeValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", variableWithLastBackupValue);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```